# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi Friends New Problem :( .

```
Private Sub txt_BarCode_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txt_BarCode.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        Dim COM As New OleDbCommand
        Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection
        con1.ConnectionString = "Provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=..\library.mdb"
        Dim READER As OleDbDataReader
        Try
            con1.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "select * from Book_Entry where barcodeno='" & txt_BarCode.Text & "'"
            COM = New OleDbCommand(query, con1)
            READER = COM.ExecuteReader
            While READER.Read
                DTPicker1.Value = READER.GetDateTime("0")
                txt_BarCode.Text = READER.GetInt32("1")
                txt_Accession.Text = READER.GetString("2")
                txt_CallNo.Text = READER.GetString("3")
                txt_Author.Text = READER.GetString("4")
                cmb_Subject.Text = READER.GetString("5")
                txt_Title.Text = READER.GetString("6")
                txt_Edition.Text = READER.GetString("7")
                cmb_Publication.Text = READER.GetString("8")
                txt_PubliPlace.Text = READER.GetString("9")
                txt_Year.Text = READER.GetInt32("10")
                txt_Pages.Text = READER.GetString("11")
                txt_Size.Text = READER.GetString("12")
                cmb_Vendor.Text = READER.GetString("13")
                txt_Cost.Text = READER.GetString("14")
                txt_Remark.Text = READER.GetString("15")

                If (READER.GetString("16") = "Text") Then
                    rdo_Text.Checked = True
                ElseIf (READER.GetString("16") = "Reference") Then
                    rdo_Reference.Checked = True
                ElseIf (READER.GetString("16") = "Book Bank") Then
                    rdo_BookBank.Checked = True
                ElseIf (READER.GetString("16") = "Study Material") Then
                    rdo_Study.Checked = True
                End If


            End While
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Please help me friends :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means that you are comparing two values of incompatible types.  You are wrapping your `barcodeno` value in single quotes, which denotes a string, yet this line:

```
txt_BarCode.Text = READER.GetInt32("1")
```

suggests that it is a number.  If it's a number then don't use single quotes.  The immediate effect of that would be to replace this:

```
query = "select * from Book_Entry where barcodeno='" & txt_BarCode.Text & "'"
```

with this:

```
query = "select * from Book_Entry where barcodeno=" & txt_BarCode.Text
```

That's not really ideal either though.  You should be validating the input and converting it to a number and then using a parameter like so:

```
query = "select * from Book_Entry where barcodeno = @barcodeno"
'...
COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcodeno", theNumber)
```

You seem very confused where data types are concerned because this line:

```
txt_BarCode.Text = READER.GetInt32("1")
```

and its like are actually wrong too.  `GetInt32` and similar methods take a field index, i.e. an `Integer`, **not** a `String`.  That should be:

```
txt_BarCode.Text = READER.GetInt32(1)
```

It's a small change and the system actually handles the conversion implicitly as it is but it's bad practice to rely on implicit conversions like that and silly to do so when it's actually more work to enter the extra characters to make it a `String` in the first place.  Do what you mean; if you mean an index then provide an index.  I strongly suggest that you turn `Option Strict On` and it will then prevent your making mistakes like that.

Actually, I just noticed that that code is still wrong based on data types and wouldn't compile with `Option Strict On`.  `GetInt32` returns an `Integer` and the `Text` of a `TextBox` requires a `String`.  To avoid an implicit conversion, which is required with `Option Strict On`, you should do this:

```
txt_BarCode.Text = READER.GetInt32(1).ToString()
```

It might seem like that sort of thing actually makes your life harder but it will force you to be aware of data types all the time and therefore be less likely to make mistakes; mistakes that can be hard to find when your code gets more complex.  Also, those mistakes will be more likely to show up at design time rather than at run time, where they might not be picked up until after release.

Comment: Thanks Dude... Really helped me.. Actually I m new to .net Programming. Once again thanks.